# How to prevent first rerendering Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, formik

I started using the `<AutoSave/>` component created [by Jared Palmer](https://twitter.com/jaredpalmer/status/1134141652191404033):

```
const AutoSave = ({debounceMs}) => {
  const formik = useFormikContext()

  const debouncedSubmit = useCallback(
    debounce(formik.submitForm, debounceMs),
    [formik.submitForm, debounceMs]
  )

  useEffect(() => debouncedSubmit, [debouncedSubmit, formik.values])

  return <>{!!formik.isSubmitting && 'saving...'}</>
}
```

The main problem is when I enter the page, `<AutoSave/>` submits the form once the page is mounted, how to prevent this behavior?

Example:

```
<Formik onSubmit={values => callMyApi(values)} initialValues={{bla: 'bla-bla'}}>
  {() => (
    //...My beautiful field components...
    <AutoSave debounceMs={300}/>
  )}
</Formik>
```

Comment: `{() => ( )}` why are you using a function there?

Comment: @Deda, what should I use instead? Check Formik 2 release, render prop is deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I didn't get a normal idea. Decided to use flag with hook `usePrevious`:

```
import {useRef} from 'react'

const usePrevious = value => {
  const ref = useRef()
  const prev = ref.current
  ref.current = value
  return prev
}
```

Now it looks like:

```
const MyForm = () => {
  const [shouldUpdate, setShouldUpdate] = useState(false)
  const previousShouldUpdate = usePrevious(shouldUpdate)

  useEffect(() => {
    setShouldUpdate(true)
    return () => {setShouldUpdate(false)}
  }, [])

  <Formik onSubmit={values => {
    if (previousShouldUpdate) {
      return callMyApi(values)
    }
  }} initialValues={{bla: 'bla-bla'}}>
    {() => (
      //...My beautiful field components...
      <AutoSave debounceMs={300}/>
    )}
  </Formik>
}
```

Any ideas to make it better?